# What are the differences between the console.log extension in Chrome for desktop and for iOS?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, console.log

I've written a Javascript app and used console.log with format strings to help debug. It works fine on Chrome on Mac desktop. On Chrome for iOS, it logs the format strings instead of the corresponding positional parameters.

What I tried was...
I hunted around the Chrome Developers website on the Formatting console.log messages page here: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/format-style/, and tried out the new YOu.com search engine, but couldn't find the docs that say that console.log works differently on iOS Chrome.

Do I need to re-write my console log messages into the style of "msg1" + "msg2" + ... ?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Chrome or another script incorrectly overrides console.log. Try using console.info.

Comment: @wOxxOm thank you for the suggestion. I tried using the '+ "foo" + <object> syntax, but I lost the formatting of %f floats and of objects so far.